# How do I elegantly return 1.0 if the value returned is 0, in 1 line?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have this statement:

```
> zv.sum(:volume).to_f || 1.0
   (0.5ms)  SELECT SUM("positions"."volume") FROM "positions" WHERE "positions"."volume" = $1  [["volume", 0]]
=> 0.0
```

What I would like to happen is if `zv.sum(:volume)` returns `0.0`, I want it to return `1.0` instead.

I know I could do a verbose `if`/`unless` statement, but I would like to do it elegantly in 1 line above.

How do I do that?

Comment: What is it return `0.1`? Should it return `0.1` or still `1.0`?

Answer (score 5):

You literally have the solution in your title and in your question (**bold** emphasis mine):

> How do I elegantly return 1.0 **if** the value returned is 0, in 1 line?
>
> What I would like to happen is **if `zv.sum(:volume)` returns `0.0`**, I want it to **return `1.0`** instead.

So, the best way would be to use a *conditional expression*:

```rb
sum = zv.sum(:volume).to_f

if sum == 0.0
  1.0
else
  sum
end
```

If you want to "optimize" this, you could move the conversion to float to the very edge of the expression:

```rb
sum = zv.sum(:volume)

if sum == 0
  1
else
  sum
end.to_f
```

[Note, this assumes that the value of `zv.sum(:volume)` will be a number and not something like `nil` or a string representing a number. If that is guaranteed, this same transformation can also be applied to every single one of the following examples.]

The requirement to do something in 1 line is *always trivially achievable* in Ruby, since line breaks are always optional. For example:

```rb
sum = zv.sum(:volume).to_f; if sum == 0.0 then 1.0 else sum end
```

Or if you want to avoid using keywords:

```rb
sum = zv.sum(:volume).to_f; if sum == 0.0; 1.0 else sum end
```

There is also the *conditional operator*, but personally, I see no use for it that cannot also (and better) be served by a conditional expression:

```rb
sum = zv.sum(:volume).to_f; sum == 0.0 ? 1.0 : sum
```

If you want a single expression, you could inline the variable assignment into the conditional:

```rb
if (sum = zv.sum(:volume).to_f) == 0.0
  1.0
else
  sum
end
```

And of course, you can combine the two:

```rb
if (sum = zv.sum(:volume).to_f) == 0.0 then 1.0 else sum end
```

And with avoiding keywords:

```rb
if (sum = zv.sum(:volume).to_f) == 0.0; 1.0 else sum end
```

And with the (still useless) conditional operator:

```rb
(sum = zv.sum(:volume).to_f) == 0.0 ? 1.0 : sum
```

If you don't mind some mildly complex non-local control flow, you could do something like this:

```rb
zv.sum(:volume).to_f.tap {|sum| break 1.0 if sum == 0.0 }
```

Pulling out the float conversion:

```rb
zv.sum(:volume).tap {|sum| break 1 if sum == 0 }.to_f
```

Also, if you know something special about the sum, for example, if you know that the sum will always be either exactly 0 or greater than 1, then you could exploit that extra knowledge and maybe do something like this:

```rb
[1.0, zv.sum(:volume).to_f].max
```

Pulling out the float conversion:

```rb
[1, zv.sum(:volume)].max.to_f
```

However, please note that *none of those* is as readable and clear as the first version.

Also, please note that the description in your question and the code in your question don't match up, since the code doesn't do what you describe in the question.

Comment: Or move the logic to a well-named function and stop all the shenanigans ;)

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`nonzero?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Numeric.html#method-i-nonzero-3F) to treat zero as a falsey value:

```
zv.sum(:volume).to_f.nonzero? || 1.0
```

or:

```
(zv.sum(:volume).nonzero? || 1).to_f
```

Comment: I expect that 90%+ of those unfamiliar with `nonzero?` (myself included) would assume it returns `true` or `false`, raising the question of whether it is a useful addition to the Ruby core.

Answer (score 1):

I usually prefer something verbose and well readable, for example :

```rb
def some_method
  volume = zv.sum(:volume).to_f
  return 1.0 if volume.zero? 

  volume
end
```

but if you really want your one-liner, you could do something like that :

`zv.sum(:volume).to_f.yield_self { |r| r.zero? ? 1.0 : r }`